# crash. QObject::connect in a constructor of a static object instance

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, qt, static-members

I'm trying to find out why my app crashes for the whole day. A picture worth thousands of words, so take a look at this code.  Header:

```
class SandboxedAppStat : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void pidsTimerTimeout();

public:
    QTimer m_PidsTimer;

    SandboxedAppStat(QObject *parent = NULL);
};

class SandboxedApp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    static SandboxedAppStat SandboxedAppStat1;
};
```

Implementation:

```
void SandboxedAppStat::pidsTimerTimeout()
{
    qDebug() << "whatever";
}

SandboxedAppStat::SandboxedAppStat(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    bool b = QObject::connect(&m_PidsTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), 
            this, SLOT(pidsTimerTimeout()));
    m_PidsTimer.start(500);
}

SandboxedAppStat SandboxedApp::SandboxedAppStat1;
```

Actually what I'm trying to do, is to simulate static constructor behavior in C++. I want

```
QObject::connect(&m_PidsTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), 
        this, SLOT(pidsTimerTimeout()));
m_PidsTimer.start(500);
```

to be called as soon as the static member SandboxedAppStat1 initializes. That's why the code shown above is in the constructor of SandboxedAppStat.

However, my problem is that when I run the program, it crashes as soon as it reaches the line `connect(&m_PidsTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(pidsTimerTimeout()));`

with error code c0000005 (access violation I guess). 
here's the screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/Untitled.gif

If I declare SandboxedAppStat as a non static variable, then there is no crash and no errors. everything works fine.

First I thought that crash reason could be the fact that, static members are initialized too early for QObject::connect to be able to be called, that's why I updated SandboxedAppStat constructor with the following code:

```
auto *t = this;
QtConcurrent::run([&] () {
    Sleep(3000);
    bool b = QObject::connect(&(t->m_PidsTimer), 
        SIGNAL(timeout()), t, SLOT(pidsTimerTimeout()));
    t->m_PidsTimer.start(500);
});
```

As you can see, QObject::connect executes after 3 seconds when static SanboxedAppStat is initialized, but this didn't help either, the program crashes after 3 seconds.

I'm really confused, I don't understand what can be the cause of this problem. Can't we use signal/slots in a static object instances?

I'm using Qt 4.8.0 with MSVC 2010.  Thanks

UPDATE

Here's a simple project, consisting of only one header and one source file (as HostileFork suggested) to reproduce the crash. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/untitled1.zip

Comment: I don't believe this code will compile. Look at this line: `bool b = QObject::connect(&m_PidsTimer), SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(pidsTimerTimeout()));`. Parentheses aren't well paired.

Comment: Have you tried building a minimal program example that is *just* a header file containing your class prototypes and an implementation file?  I did that on Linux w/4.8 and it didn't crash, but there was a warning in the debug output that you couldn't start a QTimer on threads not started with QThread (which is presumably due to trying to start a timer prior to getting into the QApplication loop).

Comment: @dschulz, possible, I stripped some code while pasting here and I could make a mistake, but this doesn't change the picture.

Comment: @HostileFork starting the timer from another thread is not causing the crash, I already checked that.

Comment: @Davita I didn't say it caused the crash (as evidenced by the fact that I said my machine didn't crash).  I said that Qt's debug output--were it to get to the line *instead* of crashing on the line before--would inform you that you can't start a timer that early.  Try what I suggested to make a project that is minimal and see if you still get the crash.  That will isolate the problem and ensure it's not coming from something else in your project that you haven't pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for periodic calling of your `pidsTimerTimeout` slot or just once during construction?

If you're looking to just receive a signal once your class has been constructed try using `QTimer::singleShot` or `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` if you don't require continuous time outs. Like all signals the single shot will only be acted upon once the **window system's event queue have been processed** which can have a small delay on the execution of your slot.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    // Using a zero singles shot.
    QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT( initialized() ) );

    // or using invoke method.
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod( this, "initialized", Qt::QueuedConnection );

}
```

Pretty sure we use this code in the office and we have success with static objects.